# Explanation of Dictionary Initialisation Syntax (C#)

Tags: c#

I found an example showing that a dictionary can be initialised as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"cat", 2},
    {"dog", 1},
    {"llama", 0},
    {"iguana", -1}
};
```

I don't understand how the syntax `{"cat", 2}` is valid for creating a Key-Value Pair. Collection initialisation syntax seems to be of the form `new MyObjType(){}`, while anonymous objects are of the form `{a="a", b="b"}`. What is actually happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright lets take a look at the code here:

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>() 
{ 
    {"cat", 2}, 
    {"dog", 1}, 
    {"llama", 0}, 
    {"iguana", -1} 
};
```

a dictionary holds two things, a key, and a value.
your declaration, `Dictionary<string, int>`, means the keys are strings, and the values are integers.

now, when your adding an item, for instance `{"cat", 2},`, the key is cat. this would be equivilent to you doing something like, `d.Add("cat", 2);`. a dictionary can hold anything, from `<string, string>` to `<customClass, anotherCustomClass>`. and to call it up you can use `int CAT = d["cat"];` to which the value of `int CAT` would be 2. an example of this would be:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>() 
{ 
    {"cat", 1}
};
dict.Add("dog", 2);
Console.WriteLine("Cat="+dict["cat"].ToString()+", Dog="+dict["dog"].ToString());
```

in in there, your adding cat and dog with different values and calling them up

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` is an `ICollection` of `KeyValuePair`s. `{"cat", 2}` is a `KeyValuePair`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what your question is asking, but the answer is that this is the syntax for collection initialization that provides a shortcut to the Add method.

This works too, for example:

```
new List<DateTime>()
{
    {DateTime.Now},
    {new DateTime()},
    {DateTime.Now}
}
```

Usually when the question is "why is this valid", the answer is because "it is valid" :)

Note that the syntax you specified in the latter part of the question is not just for anonymous objects, its for any object with public property setters:

```
new MyPerson("Bob")
{
    Address = "185 What St",
    DoB = DateTime.Now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a key value pairing. The `Dictionary<string,int>` says the key will be a `string` and the value will be an `int`. Thus with `{"cat", 2}` you have a key of `"cat"` and a value of `2`. Why you would have a key of cat and a value of 2, I am not sure, but never the less it is an example of a Dictionary<> with a string key and an int value. More info and examples can be found here:

[MSDN Dictionary<> with Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)